# WPF TreeView not showing childs

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm implementing a custom designed FolderSelector and I'm using a TreeView to show the folders.

This is the view:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="viewModel:FolderViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <DockPanel>
                <fa:FontAwesome Icon="FolderOutline" Foreground="#dd5d18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
            </DockPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

This is the viewmodel for the whole dialog

```
internal class FolderBrowserViewModel : BaseBAObject
{
    #region Fields        

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<FolderViewModel> Items { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public FolderBrowserViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<FolderViewModel>();
        LoadItems();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void LoadItems()
    {
        try
        {
            var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (var drive in drives)
            {
                Items.Add(new FolderViewModel(drive.Name.Replace(@":\", ""), drive.Name));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And this is the viewmodel for every folder

```
internal class FolderViewModel : BaseBAObject
{
    #region Fields
    private bool _isSelected;
    private bool _isLoaded;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Path { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<FolderViewModel> Items { get; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));

                LoadSubfolders();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    public FolderViewModel(string name, string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        Name = name;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<FolderViewModel>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void LoadSubfolders(bool force = false)
    {
        if(_isLoaded && !force)
            return;

        try
        {
            var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Path);

            Items.Clear();
            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                Items.Add(new FolderViewModel(dir, System.IO.Path.Combine(Path, dir)));
            }

            _isLoaded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I'm now facing several problems

- The data template is not applied to the TreeView root objects nor childs
- The childs are not displayed (they are properly loaded when a root item is selected)
- I want to show a unlimited count of childs

Comment: Use x:Type when you specfify the DataType and it should work. Please refer to my (edited) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be explicit about the type argument, i.e. use `{x:Type}`, and bind the `Content` property of the `Label` to the `Name` property of the `FolderViewModel`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FolderViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
    </DockPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry, this was my copy-paste mistake. It's like this is the original code.

Comment: Now my application is crashing due to a StackOverflowException

Comment: Then you have written some bad code somewhere because the sample code you have posted works for me when I uncomment the irrelevant BaseBAObject and INotifyPropertyChanged stuff. Please provide a full repo if you need any further help. At least you know how to apply your template now which was your original question.